# How to Fix the bug Local processing Exception was unhandled when passing parameter to report rdlc winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am doing college project. In that, they want a bonafide certificate. For that, I planned to pass `TextBox` string to report.

I googled for passing parameter in a winform. Then I got this step by step process. I implement that.

> Step:
>
> 1: In Visual Studio 2010, open your
>   .rdlc file, and open “Report Data”
>   window (If you can not see this
>   window, go to View menu to open it);
>
> 2: Right click the “Parameters” node,
>   and add a new Parameter, ie: named it
>   “content“;
>
> 3: In your .rdlc file, add a textbox,
>   named it tbContent, and set its filed
>   express to :
>
> =Parameters!content.Value
>
> 4: Go to your Form file which include
>   your reporterview control, and add the
>   following code:
>
> ```
>        this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource
> ```
>
> = “TestReport.Report1.rdlc”;
>               ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter(“content”,
>   this.textBox1.Text);
>               this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new
>   ReportParameter[] { rp });
>               this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
>
> 5: then you can pass the parameter
>   from the TextBox on the form to .rdlc
>   file;

I added `using Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;` assembly reference.

```
 this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc";

            ReportParameter rp = new ReportParameter("content", this.textBox1.Text);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { rp });
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

But it throws the exception:

> Local processing Exception was
>   unhandled at
>   this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new
>   ReportParameter[] { rp }); 
>   line.

Here's the full error from the clipboard:

```
  Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred during local report processing.
  Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at Report.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\Jagadeeswaran\Project\Report\Report\Form1.cs:line 38
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.SafeNativeMethods.ShowWindow(HandleRef hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Visible(Boolean value)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Report.Program.Main() in D:\Jagadeeswaran\Project\Report\Report\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ApplicationException
       Message=The report definition for report 'D:\Jagadeeswaran\Project\Report\Report\bin\Debug\~/Report1.rdlc' has not been specified
       Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Reporting.PreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContextBase context, Boolean rebuild, Byte[]& reportDefinition, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContextBase itemContext, Boolean rebuild, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()
       InnerException: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException
            Message=Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Jagadeeswaran\Project\Report\Report\bin\Debug\~\Report1.rdlc'.
            Source=mscorlib
            StackTrace:
                 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
                 at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
                 at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.StandalonePreviewStore.GetReportDefinition(ReportID reportId)
                 at Microsoft.Reporting.PreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContextBase context, Boolean rebuild, Byte[]& reportDefinition, ControlSnapshot& snapshot)
            InnerException:
```

Comment: I start searching  Solution for this problem in yesterday night. I read many question like this. So many people was affected in this Problem.(mostly vb.net) One of them surely got the Solution. But they didn't share. I continue my search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set this:

```
this.reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = 
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
```

And change this:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc"
```

to

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";
```

Comment: if some expression in rdlc have a bug or you want to read null parameter value ,or any syntax error or runtime error exist in rdl file can cause this error,if i had your rdlc file could help you more

Answer (score 2):

Just in case that this would be the case, I had the same problem after I reorganized my project folders, thus changing the report file path. All I had to do is re-selecting the report in the ReportViewer's Choose Report ComboBox accessible from its upper-right corner.

Answer (score 1):

also double check that you are spelling your `rdlc` filename correctly. For example, my report file was `ReportName.rdlc` but I had typed in `this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportsName.rdlc";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use embedded just fine, just don't forget to include the name space in the RDLC path.  The assembly namespace is required, as well as any possible sub namespaces you might have as the full namespace path to the report.

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "assemblyname.Report1.rdlc"
```

or

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "assemblyname.subnamespace.Report1.rdlc"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just run `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` in "NuGet Package Manager Console" and everything is working well.